# How do I reset a flutter project , Xcode fails

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios

My project builds and runs fine in vscode. I did have a widget which I just delete.

My project HAS built in Xcode, and in fact is running on my phone.

So now I can't get the project to build in Xcode, I get a 'module not found' on one of my modules which I believe is symptom of some other hidden error.

How can I remove and reset any and all code that Xcode has added, in hopes of a fresh start with it?

---

the error

CompileC /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-asxelbzjibprohcrxatlfkojolzw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.o /Users/xxx/Projects/timetocall/time_to_call/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
cd /Users/xxx/Projects/timetocall/time_to_call/ios
export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -target arm64-apple-ios14.5 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Wno-objc-interface-ivars -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wimplicit-retain-self -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wdeprecated-implementations -DCOCOAPODS=1 -DCOCOAPODS=1 -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.5.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -iquote /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-asxelbzjibprohcrxatlfkojolzw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Runner-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-asxelbzjibprohcrxatlfkojolzw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Runner-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-asxelbzjibprohcrxatlfkojolzw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Runner-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-asxelbzjibprohcrxatlfkojolzw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Runner-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-asxelbzjibprohcrxatlfkojolzw/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/include -I/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-asxelbzjibprohcrxatlfkojolzw/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FMDB/FMDB.framework/Headers -I/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-asxelbzjibprohcrxatlfkojolzw/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/sqflite/sqflite.framework/Headers -I/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-asxelbzjibprohcrxatlfkojolzw/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FMDB/FMDB.framework/Headers -I/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-asxelbzjibprohcrxatlfkojolzw/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/sqflite/sqflite.framework/Headers -I/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-asxelbzjibprohcrxatlfkojolzw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/DerivedSources-normal/arm64 -I/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-asxelbzjibprohcrxatlfkojolzw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -I/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-asxelbzjibprohcrxatlfkojolzw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-asxelbzjibprohcrxatlfkojolzw/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-asxelbzjibprohcrxatlfkojolzw/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FMDB -F/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-asxelbzjibprohcrxatlfkojolzw/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/sqflite -F/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-asxelbzjibprohcrxatlfkojolzw/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FMDB -F/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-asxelbzjibprohcrxatlfkojolzw/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/sqflite -F/Users/xxx/Projects/timetocall/time_to_call/ios/Flutter -F/Users/xxx/Projects/timetocall/time_to_call/ios -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-asxelbzjibprohcrxatlfkojolzw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-asxelbzjibprohcrxatlfkojolzw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.dia -c /Users/xxx/Projects/timetocall/time_to_call/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m -o /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-asxelbzjibprohcrxatlfkojolzw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.o

/Users/xxx/Projects/timetocall/time_to_call/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:10:9: fatal error: module 'sqflite' not found
@import sqflite;

```
1 error generated.
```

Comment: I've gone a bit heavy and am using this to build, which hasn't helped Xcode..        flutter clean
rm -rf ./build/
flutter pub get
cd ios
pod install
pod upgrade
cd ../
flutter build ios lib/screens/main.dart

Comment: Hi There. Post your exact error.

Comment: Kindly post the error for better understanding of the community.

Comment: updated with error

Answer (score 0):

Well , seems I needed to update my idea of how to build for my device,
I removed by build folders

rm -rf ./build
then
used Xcode->product->clean build folder

Then it build and deployed fine.